# Modify XML node using Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing

I am taking an XML file as an input, have to search with a keyword i.e `GENTEST05`.
If found , then I need to pick up its parent node (in this example I want to pick up `<ScriptElement>`) and then replace the complete node `<ScriptElement>blahblah</ScriptElement>` with a new content.

```
...
...
<ScriptElement>
<ScriptElement>
<ScriptElement>
    <ElementData xsi:type="anyData">
        <DeltaTime>
        <Area>
        <Datatype>USER PROMPT [GENTEST05]</Datatype>
        <Description />
        <Multipartmessage>False<Multipartmessage>
        <Comment>false</Comment>
    </ElementData>
</ScriptElement>
<ScriptElement>
<ScriptElement>
...
...
...
```

I am trying to do this using Beautifulsoup. This is what I've done so far but not getting a proper way to proceed. Other than beautifulsoup, ElementTree or any other suggestion is welcome.

```
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup as bs
xmlsoup = bs(open('file_xml' , 'r'))

a = raw_input('Enter Text')
paraText = xmlsoup.findAll(text=a)
print paraText
print paraText.findParent()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is some sample code to get you started. I used ElementTree because it's a builtin module and quite suitable for this type of task.

Here is the XML file I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Script>
    <ScriptElement/>
    <ScriptElement/>
    <ScriptElement>
        <ElementData>
            <DeltaTime/>
            <Area/>
            <Datatype>USER PROMPT [GENTEST05]</Datatype>
            <Description/>
            <Multipartmessage>False</Multipartmessage>
            <Comment>false</Comment>
        </ElementData>
    </ScriptElement>
    <ScriptElement/>
    <ScriptElement/>
</Script>
```

Here is the python program:

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

#The keyword to find and remove
keyword = "GENTEST05"

for element in list(root):

    for sub in element.iter():

        if sub.text and keyword in sub.text:
            root.remove(element)
            print ElementTree.tostring(root)
            sys.exit()
```

I have kept the program simple so that you can improve on it. Since your XML has one root node, I am assuming you want to remove all parent elements of the keyword-matched element directly up to the root. In ElementTree, you can call root.remove() to remove the `<ScriptElement>` element that is the ancestory of the keyword-matched element.

This is just to get you started: this will only remove the first element, then print the resulting tree and quit.

Output:

```
<Script>
    <ScriptElement />
    <ScriptElement />
    <ScriptElement />
    <ScriptElement />
</Script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . for line 'if sub.text and keyword in sub.text:' getting error 'str obj is not callable'

Comment: Hmm, that error sounds like you are trying to use a string as a function like so: `"imastring"()`. Make sure that none of your string variables have accidental function calls attached to them. If you can't figure it out, open a new question. Good luck!